# How to make client side script variable dynamic within a repeat

Tags: javascript, dynamic, xpages, repeat, serverside-javascript

I am trying to output som script using SSJS from a computedField like so:

```
var outScript = "<script>var data = " + datad.toString() + ";</script>"
```

The problem I have is that the computedField is within a doccollection repeat so I need to make the variable dynamic because I later need to access only the variable from the current entry using client side javascript (also within repeat)

How do I write to make the "data" variable dynamic within my repeat?

I know can create the variable using noteid or index, but I need to know how to write to output the variable i.e data1, data2 etc.

Hope you understand, a bit complicated to explain. 
problably an easy answer I havn't thought of

thanks
Thomas

Comment: It works, but it is very bad idea to compute script by computedText control. By default it gets evaluated several times during every refresh (because of JSF life cycle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the repeat's **indexVar** to save the data with a distinct key for each repeat entry:

```
var outScript = "<script>window.data_myRepeat_" + iRepeat.toFixed(0) + " = " + datad.toString() + ";</script>"
```

Here, it is assumed that the repeat's ID is "myRepeat" and indexVar is "iRepeat".